# WP_Query doesn't works inside loop

Tags: wp-query, loop, filters, children

I'm trying to show a category and his children with this structure (whit this content()):

```
 - Category Father title
     - Children title
     - Other children title
 - Category Father title
     - ....
```

But with this code

```
$catH = array(11);
$query = array("cat"=>42,"order"=>"ASC","posts_per_page"=>-1,"category__not_in"=>$catH);
$obj = new WP_Query($query);
if ($obj->have_posts()){    
    while($obj->have_posts()){
        $obj->the_post();
        $slug = get_the_tags();         
        the_title();
        echo "<br/>";
        $queryH = array("cat"=>13,"order"=>"ASC","posts_per_page"=>-1,"tag__in"=>$slug);
        $objH = new WP_Query($queryH);
        if ($objH->have_posts()){
            while($objH->have_posts()){
                $objH->the_post();
                the_title();
                echo "<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();    
}
```

The result is like that:

- Category Father title
- Category Father title
- Children title
- Other children title

How can I fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
if ($obj->have_posts()){    
    while($obj->have_posts()){
        $obj->the_post();
        $slug = get_the_tags();         
        $obj->the_title();
        echo "<br/>";
        $queryH = array("cat"=>13,"order"=>"ASC","posts_per_page"=>-1,"tag__in"=>$slug);
        $objH = new WP_Query($queryH);
        if ($objH->have_posts()){
            while($objH->have_posts()){
                $objH->the_post();
                $objH->the_title();
                echo "<br/>";
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: I've try and the result is similiar to what I need. Thanks!